# Python: convert np.ndarray of float32 to sequence of bytes

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-3.7, librosa

I have an array of floats that is output by the librosa library load function that I would like to convert to an AudioData needed by google SpeechRecognition library

The data formats are shown below

Side note: these are read from comments in library files, I cannot find strict definitions like in C

Librosa.load returns

```
Returns
-------
y    : np.ndarray [shape=(n,) or (2, n)]
    audio time series
```

SpeechRecognition.AudioData class takes frame_data which is a string of bytes Im understanding

```
The raw audio data is specified by ``frame_data``, which is a sequence of bytes representing audio samples. This is the frame data structure used by the PCM WAV format.
```

How can In convert from `ndaarray of floats` to `sequence of bytes` in python

In Visual Studio Code, `audio` as returned by librosa is

```
dtype:dtype('float32')
alignment:4
base:dtype('float32')
byteorder:'='
char:'f'
descr:[('', '<f4')]
fields:None
flags:0
hasobject:False
isalignedstruct:False
isbuiltin:1
isnative:True
itemsize:4
kind:'f'
metadata:None
name:'float32'
names:None
```

The full code Im trying to run is:

```
# importing libraries 
import speech_recognition as spr 
import librosa

audio, sr = librosa.load('sample_data.mp3')

print(audio)

# create a speech recognition object 

#conversion needed here
audio2 = spr.AudioData() 

r = spr.Recognizer() 
r.recognize_google(audio2)
```

Thanks,

Comment: You asked the same question, right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60879469/audio-data-must-be-audio-data-error-with-google-speech-recognition-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Audio data must be audio data' error with google speech recognition in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60879469/audio-data-must-be-audio-data-error-with-google-speech-recognition-in-python)